# Is there a limit on XMS and XMX settings for 64 bit OS

Tags: jboss

Hi I am trying to find the limit for `xms` and `xmx` on a `64 bit 2008R2 platform`.

I have limited knowledge of this area.

Can anyone tell me if there are any issues with setting xmx and xms to 18gig. I have read about issues with garbage collection. The server has 24gig.

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 0):

I am running 65536M on 2008 R2 64-bit with no issues.  Machine has 32GB physical (well, it's actually a VM, so it's virtual, but what isn't?).  I actually came to your question to see if going to 96GB on a 32GB VM would be an issue, other than more disk thrashing.